# Maven test, build failure, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running mvn test in Eclipse on a Maven Project. The JUnit tests pass, but i get a stack trace error which is below. It's got to do with the javax.peristence.Persistence class I think. I did a bit of research and I think I need to add the javax library to the class path (getting some advice on how to do that would be great. I have put this dependency in the pom.xml, but still get the error. I thought listing it explicitly in the pom.xml would solve my problems.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.399 sec <<< FAILURE! -   

 in tableTests.TestBaseDataConfig

 testCreateDeleteRow(tableTests.TestBaseDataConfig)  Time elapsed: 0.087 sec  <<< ERROR!

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at persistence.PersistenceUtil.<clinit>(PersistenceUtil.java:12)
at config.AbstractTableConfig.createRow(AbstractTableConfig.java:11)
at tableTests.TestBaseDataConfig.testCreateDeleteRow(TestBaseDataConfig.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only declaring dependency to ejb3-hibernate **pom**, not the actual jar artifact. Try removing `<type>pom</type>`